# React Native Error type 3: Activity Class {...} does not exist

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I took over a project written in React Native, but this project is a bit strange, I can generate apk to install, but using `npx react-native run-android` will get `Error: Activity class {com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity} does not exist.`

In fact this file does not exist, I also checked some information, but it didn't help me, then I use `npx react-native run-android --appId com.ooo.ooo` , the result will appear `Error: Activity class {com.ooo.ooo/com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity} does not exist.`

Even if the previous id is correct, it still results in a MainActivity that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the project is using flavors/variants with different appIds or suffixes, then (I just learned after much consternation+research) that needs to be accounted for in the launch command.

So for instance if `applicationId="com.example.myapp"` (and presumably in RN 0.70+, you also have `namespace="com.example.myapp"` as well), plus you have in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
    flavorDimensions "build"
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "build"
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
    }
```

Then the error you would be seeing doesn't account for that with the default `react-native run-android` command, which would show something like:

```
Error type 3 
Error: Activity class
{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

I would have thought using the variant option of `react-native run-android --variant 'devDebug'` would have accounted for it, but apparently not.

So just amend your command/script to call it as `react-native run-android --variant 'devDebug' --appIdSuffix 'dev'`, and then it should launch with a successful response of:

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.example.myapp.dev/com.example.myapp.MainActivity }
```

Of course, adjust for your specific configs.

HTH! Wish I'd realized the issue many hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Greg Haygood. That's it!

About my case: I upgraded react-native from 0.71 to 0.73.4. And now there is no option `--variant`. It is recommended to use `--mode` instead. So the build was successful, but then I got the same errors

Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.example/com.example.myapp.MainActivity} does not exist.

Now I call it with `-mode flavourDebug --appIdSuffix 'flavoursuffix'` and it works fine